# flask_login, login_manager.user_loader is not getting called

Tags: flask, okta

I am using flask_login, It worked in local but when i moved to different server it is did not work. On trying to debug i realized login_manager.user_loader is not getting on remote machine but the same worked in my local.

This is issue is specific to okta sso authentication on remote machine only. Post okta authentication, i am calling below to save data in session.

login_user(user)

Post this, i was expecting user_loaded to be called but that is not happening. Tried going through document but could not understand. Can you anyone help me as why user_loader is getting called in my local machine but not on remote machine.

**init**.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from config import app_config

login_manager = LoginManager()


def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__, 
                instance_path=os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.curdir), 'instance'), 
                instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

    login_manager.init_app(app)
    login_manager.login_message = 'You must be logged in to access this page'
    login_manager.login_view = 'admin.login'
    login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'
    login_manager.session_protection = "strong"
    #login_manager.refresh_view ='admin.login'
    #login_manager.needs_refresh_message = (u"To protect your account, please reauthenticate to access this page.")
    

    from .home import home as home_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(home_blueprint)

    from .restapi import restapi as restapi_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(restapi_blueprint, url_prefix='/steps/api/v1')

    return app
```

In my blueprint view, i am calling login_user to set current user. I have placed user_loader in one seperate file.

```
from flask import current_app
from flask_login import UserMixin

from app import login_manager, get_connection
from .encryption import encrypt_json, encrypt_password, decrypt_password # noqa


class User(UserMixin):

    """Custom User class."""
    id = None
    name = None
    email = None
    description = None
    role = None

    def __init__(self, id_, name, email, description, role):
        print(name)
        self.id = str(id_)
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.description = description
        self.role = role
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def claims(self):
        """Use this method to render all assigned claims on profile page."""
        return {'name': self.name,
                'email': self.email}.items()

    @staticmethod
    def get(user_id):
        try:
            connection = get_connection()
            user_sql = "SELECT ID, USER_NAME, DESCRIPTION, EMAIL, ROLE FROM USER WHERE ID = {}"

            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(user_sql.format(user_id))
            data = cursor.fetchone()
            if data:                
                return User(id_=data[0], name=data[1], email=data[3], description=data[2], role=data[4]) 
            else:
                return None
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()

        # print(user_id)
        # print(USERS_DB)
        # return USERS_DB.get(user_id)


    @staticmethod
    def getByName(user_name):
        try:
            connection = get_connection()
            user_sql = "SELECT ID, USER_NAME, DESCRIPTION, EMAIL, ROLE FROM USER WHERE USER_NAME = '{}' "

            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(user_sql.format(user_name))
            data = cursor.fetchone()
            if data:                
                return User(id_=data[0], name=data[1], email=data[3], description=data[2], role=data[4]) 
            else:
                return None
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()


    @staticmethod
    def getByEmail(emailid):
        try:
            connection = get_connection()
            user_sql = "SELECT ID, USER_NAME, DESCRIPTION, EMAIL, ROLE FROM USER WHERE EMAIL = '{}' "

            cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)
            cursor.execute(user_sql.format(emailid))
            data = cursor.fetchone()
            print(data)
            if data:                
                return User(id_=data[0], name=data[1], email=data[3], description=data[2], role=data[4]) 
            else:
                return None
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()    


    @staticmethod
    def verify_password(username, password):        
        try:
            # mysql_hook = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id="STEPS", schema="STEPS")
            # connection = mysql_hook.get_conn()
            connection = get_connection()
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            encFlag, decryptedPassword = decrypt_password(password)
            lognReqTuple = (username, password)
            user_sql = "SELECT USER_NAME, PASSWORD from USER WHERE USER_NAME = '{}'"
            cursor.execute(user_sql.format(username))
            all_users = cursor.fetchall()
            print(all_users)
            for user in all_users:        
                encFlag, decryptedPassword = decrypt_password(user[1]) if user[1] else (False, password)
                existingUserTuple = user[0], decryptedPassword
                if existingUserTuple == lognReqTuple:
                    # logging.info('User {} authenticated.'.format(username))                        
                    return 0
            # logging.info('Un Authorized access, user authentication failed.')
            return 1
        except Exception as ex:
            # logging.error('Error in verifying login details :{}'.format(ex))
            print(ex)
            return 1
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()        


    @staticmethod
    def create(user_id, name, email):
        # USERS_DB[user_id] = User(user_id, name, email)
        pass


@login_manager.user_loader
def user_loader(user_id):
    print('user loader', type(user_id), user_id)
    return User.get(user_id)
```

Problem is that, same setup is working in my local ubuntu environment but when i moved to production vm on centos, it works for one view where i am using local authentication but not in case of okta.

Comment: You need to provide more details, show some code and the error logs. You also need to provide details about your Okta implementation if this is relevant to the issue at hand.

Comment: I am referring example given on https://github.com/okta/samples-python-flask/tree/master/okta-hosted-login

As per this, once the login_user is called, i can see user_loader being called also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the issue but i changed the flask app folder structure. changed the way i was using blueprints and issue got solved. All in all, had to change complete application structure.

Answer (score 1):

`user_loader` is how you obtain the `User` object. You give it an `id` and it gives you back the `User`. See the [docs](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.LoginManager.user_loader).

In your case you already have the `User` object so `login_user(user)` has no need to call the `user_loader`.

`user_loader` is likely called wherever you do something like `user = ...`.

Comment: Added sample code where i am initializing the application and associating login manager to flask app.

Comment: I am referring to https://github.com/okta/samples-python-flask/tree/master/okta-hosted-login . As per this example, post login_user call, user_loader is getting called automatically.